# Why is the android studio system image missing kernel-ranchu?

Tags: installation, android, android-studio, sdk

The command `sdkmanager --install 'system-images;android-29;google_apis;x86'` generates a folder containing the system image. When I try to start an emulator using android-29, I get an error message saying it is missing kernel-ranchu. Checking the folder, I see that there is a file named kernel-ranchu-64.

Why did the sdkmanager not install the right file? I see that the x86_64 folder contains a file named kernel-ranchu. Should I swap them, are they in the wrong place? Are there other files that are also misplaced?

This isn't some homebrewed thing - I'm using the official sdkmanager (and it does exactly the same if I use the android-studio graphical interface), freshly installed, I haven't made any tweaks or changes to anything, so it should be behaving exactly the same as it does for anyone else. Is there some secret toggle I'm missing, some extra flag I need to get it working?

Additionally (and for the benefit of future searchers), if anyone can provide a guide to how to install android-studio on ubuntu, that would be much appreciated - none of the existing tutorials I have been able to find work, due to issues like this. Maybe 18.04.2LTS is too recent a release, and it's waiting for an update?